# Declaring variables globally in nested for loop breaks the loop prematurely in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

This is a question from a java newbie!
In the following nested for loop, I have defined the looping variables globally, but it seems the iteration is broken after the innermost loop is done:

```java
class Cas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (; i < 4; i++) {
        for (; j < 2; j++) {
        System.out.printf("i %d j %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

this prints:

```sh
/tmp $ java Cas
i 0 j 0
i 0 j 1
```

but when I declare the variables directly in the for e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` all work fine. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that this way, `j` is never reset to `0` after the first run of the inner loop.

Comment: `j` will only ever be set to `0` once in your code. So the first run through the outer loop the inner loop will run, but every susequent one `j` will be >= 2 right from the start, skipping the inner loop immediately.

Comment: Read up on [various variable scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope).

Comment: You've omitted the declaration **and** the initialization, You need the initialization.  `for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)`

Comment: As the anwer to this post already makes clear, there is no magic involved here, the behavior is very logical. That's why I suggest to always initialize the variable in the for-loop *initialization* part, i.e. always use `for (int i = 0; …; …)`, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared and initialized your loop variables within the `main` method but outside either of the loops.  This makes them local variables to the `main` method.  The values held by these variables are only modified by the incrementation of the update clause of the for-loops.  Thus, the inner loop only performs a single iteration because the loop-condition is already satisfied in the subsequent entries to that loop.  See the following table.

```
Iter  i  j prints
---- -- -- ------
1     0  0  yes 
2     0  1  yes
3     0  2  no     inner iteration ends
4     1  2  no     inner iteration ends on entry
5     2  2  no     inner iteration ends on entry
6     3  2  no     inner iteration ends on entry
7     4  2  no     outer iteration ends
```

I don't know if you have a reason for composing your for-loops in this manner but the traditional form is to define and initialize the loop variables in the for-loop statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    System.out.printf("i %d j %d\n", i, j);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to set `j=0` in the outer loop, so for every iteration cycle in the inner loop, `j` is reset